# XML deserialization not loading values into class

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, deserialization

I have the following XML for which I auto-generated a class.

Once the class was generated, I had to make some adjustments to get the `PayrollEmployeePayrollDate` and `PayrollEmployeePayrollCategoryWorkCode` classes.  Since I made the adjustments, both classes are loaded but all the values are null.  I don't get any error unless they are being consumed during the deserialization process.  Why are my values not being loaded into the class?

```
<Payroll>
<StartDate>2015-02-22</StartDate>
<EndDate>2015-02-28</EndDate>
<PostedDate>2015-02-28</PostedDate>
<Employee EmployeeId="123456">
<EmployeePayStatus></EmployeePayStatus>
<PayrollStoreNumber>1111</PayrollStoreNumber>
<ReviewedDate></ReviewedDate>
<PayrollCategory Category="OT">
</PayrollCategory>
<PayrollCategory Category="DT">
</PayrollCategory>
<PayrollCategory Category="REGULAR">
<PayrollDate>2015-02-23</PayrollDate>
<Hours>5.97</Hours>
<WorkCode code="888">
<TotalHours>5.97</TotalHours>
</WorkCode>
<PayrollDate>2015-02-24</PayrollDate>
<Hours>6.07</Hours>
<WorkCode code="888">
<TotalHours>6.07</TotalHours>
</WorkCode>
<PayrollDate>2015-02-25</PayrollDate>
<Hours>6.00</Hours>
<WorkCode code="888">
<TotalHours>6.00</TotalHours>
</WorkCode>
<PayrollDate>2015-02-26</PayrollDate>
<Hours>8.44</Hours>
<WorkCode code="888">
<TotalHours>8.44</TotalHours>
</WorkCode>
<PayrollDate>2015-02-27</PayrollDate>
<Hours>7.90</Hours>
<WorkCode code="888">
<TotalHours>7.90</TotalHours>
</WorkCode>
</PayrollCategory>
<PayrollCategory Category="SICK">
</PayrollCategory>
<PayrollCategory Category="VACATION">
</PayrollCategory>
<PayrollCategory Category="HOLIDAY">
</PayrollCategory>
<PayrollCategory Category="RT">
</PayrollCategory>
<PayrollCategory Category="EO">
</PayrollCategory>
<PayrollCategory Category="RSA">
</PayrollCategory>
</Employee>
<Employee EmployeeId="987654">
<EmployeePayStatus></EmployeePayStatus>
<PayrollStoreNumber>1111</PayrollStoreNumber>
<ReviewedDate></ReviewedDate>
<PayrollCategory Category="OT">
</PayrollCategory>
<PayrollCategory Category="DT">
</PayrollCategory>
<PayrollCategory Category="REGULAR">
<PayrollDate>2015-02-23</PayrollDate>
<Hours>6.38</Hours>
<WorkCode code="888">
<TotalHours>6.38</TotalHours>
</WorkCode>
<PayrollDate>2015-02-24</PayrollDate>
<Hours>6.82</Hours>
<WorkCode code="888">
<TotalHours>6.82</TotalHours>
</WorkCode>
<PayrollDate>2015-02-25</PayrollDate>
<Hours>6.83</Hours>
<WorkCode code="888">
<TotalHours>6.83</TotalHours>
</WorkCode>
<PayrollDate>2015-02-26</PayrollDate>
<Hours>7.32</Hours>
<WorkCode code="888">
<TotalHours>7.32</TotalHours>
</WorkCode>
<PayrollDate>2015-02-27</PayrollDate>
<Hours>7.40</Hours>
<WorkCode code="888">
<TotalHours>7.40</TotalHours>
</WorkCode>
<PayrollDate>2015-02-28</PayrollDate>
<Hours>4.17</Hours>
<WorkCode code="888">
<TotalHours>4.17</TotalHours>
</WorkCode>
</PayrollCategory>
<PayrollCategory Category="SICK">
</PayrollCategory>
<PayrollCategory Category="VACATION">
</PayrollCategory>
<PayrollCategory Category="HOLIDAY">
</PayrollCategory>
<PayrollCategory Category="RT">
</PayrollCategory>
<PayrollCategory Category="EO">
</PayrollCategory>
<PayrollCategory Category="RSA">
</PayrollCategory>
</Employee>
</Payroll>
```

Here is the class I am working with.

```
namespace PayrollProcessor.BL
{
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Payroll
    {

        private System.DateTime startDateField;

        private System.DateTime endDateField;

        private System.DateTime postedDateField;

        private PayrollEmployee[] employeeField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date")]
        public System.DateTime StartDate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.startDateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.startDateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date")]
        public System.DateTime EndDate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.endDateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.endDateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date")]
        public System.DateTime PostedDate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.postedDateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.postedDateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Employee")]
        public PayrollEmployee[] Employee
        {
            get
            {
                return this.employeeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.employeeField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class PayrollEmployee
    {

        private string employeePayStatusField;

        private string payrollStoreNumberField;

        private string reviewedDateField;

        private PayrollEmployeePayrollCategory[] payrollCategoryField;

        private int employeeIdField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string EmployeePayStatus
        {
            get
            {
                return this.employeePayStatusField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.employeePayStatusField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string PayrollStoreNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return this.payrollStoreNumberField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.payrollStoreNumberField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string ReviewedDate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.reviewedDateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.reviewedDateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PayrollCategory")]
        public PayrollEmployeePayrollCategory[] PayrollCategory
        {
            get
            {
                return this.payrollCategoryField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.payrollCategoryField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public int EmployeeId
        {
            get
            {
                return this.employeeIdField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.employeeIdField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class PayrollEmployeePayrollCategory
    {
        private PayrollEmployeePayrollDate[] payrollEmployeePayrollDatesField;

        private string categoryField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Category
        {
            get
            {
                return this.categoryField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.categoryField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PayrollDate")]
        public PayrollEmployeePayrollDate[] PayrollEmployeePayrollDates
        {
            get
            {
                return payrollEmployeePayrollDatesField;
            }
            set
            {
                payrollEmployeePayrollDatesField = value;
            }
        }

    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class PayrollEmployeePayrollDate
    {
        private DateTime? paryrollDateField;

        private decimal? hours;

        private PayrollEmployeePayrollCategoryWorkCode[] payrollEmployeePayrollCategoryWorkCode;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PayrollDate", typeof(System.DateTime), DataType = "date")]
        public DateTime? PayrollDate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.paryrollDateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.paryrollDateField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Hours", typeof(decimal))]
        public decimal? Hours
        {
            get
            {
                return this.hours;
            }
            set
            {
                this.hours = value;
            }
        }

         [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("WorkCode", typeof(PayrollEmployeePayrollCategoryWorkCode))]
        public PayrollEmployeePayrollCategoryWorkCode[] WorkCode
        {
            get
            {
                return payrollEmployeePayrollCategoryWorkCode;
            }
            set
            {
                payrollEmployeePayrollCategoryWorkCode = value;
            }
        }
    }


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class PayrollEmployeePayrollCategoryWorkCode
    {

        private decimal totalHoursField;

        private int codeField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TotalHours", typeof(decimal))]
        public decimal TotalHours
        {
            get
            {
                return this.totalHoursField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.totalHoursField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public int code
        {
            get
            {
                return this.codeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.codeField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I changed the generated classes is because when I looped through the categories, I only got one date. As the XML demonstrates, there could be up to 7 dates under each category.

The XML is from a third party and I don't think I can get them to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the XML structure no longer matches up to the structure of the classes you've got.

Your XML for `PayrollCategory` looks like this:

```
<PayrollCategory Category="REGULAR">
<PayrollDate>2015-02-23</PayrollDate>
<Hours>5.97</Hours>
<WorkCode code="888">
<TotalHours>5.97</TotalHours>
</WorkCode>
<!-- ... -->
```

Note that `PayrollDate`, `Hours` and `WorkCode` elements are immediate child elements of `PayrollCategory`.

But your C# class structure for `PayrollEmployeePayrollCategory` moves all three of these elements into the child element `PayrollDate` via the `PayrollEmployeePayrollDates` property of type `PayrollEmployeePayrollDate[]`.  `PayrollEmployeePayrollDate` defines `PayrollDate`, `Hours` and `WorkCode` properties (and consequently also declares these as child elements of `PayrollDate`).

For the class structure you have now, the corresponding XML would look like:

```
<PayrollCategory Category="REGULAR">
    <PayrollDate>
        <PayrollDate>2015-02-23</PayrollDate>
        <Hours>5.97</Hours>
        <WorkCode code="888">
        <TotalHours>5.97</TotalHours>
        </WorkCode>
    </PayrollDate>
    <!-- ... -->
```

So, you've either got to adjust your classes to match the XML you have, or change your XML generation to match the new class structure if that's what you need.

UPDATE: You can't update the XML, and you want to get the grouping of `PayrollDate`/`Hours`/`WorkCode` reflected in your C# classes.

There isn't a clean solution to this, because the .NET XML serialization framework doesn't have the concept of mapping a group of elements to a class, even though this is a reasonable XML idiom (as would be represented in W3C XML Schema as a model-group `xs:group` definition).

The upside of .NET XML serialization is that it's pretty easy to do the easy stuff, but the downside is it doesn't scale that well to more complicated use cases.

An approach you could take, assuming I'm understanding your input XML structure correctly, is to store arrays for each of `PayrollDate`, `Hours` and `WorkCode` in a "flat" representation inside your class which maps to `PayrollCategory`. These would be used for the XML serialization. Then, add a property which computes a collection of objects from these XML-mapped properties, which restructures the data in the way you want it:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PayrollDate", typeof(System.DateTime), DataType = "date")]
public DateTime[] Xml_PayrollDates
{
    get;
    set;
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Hours", typeof(decimal))]
public decimal[] Xml_Hours
{
    get;
    set;
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("WorkCode", typeof(PayrollEmployeePayrollCategoryWorkCode))]
public PayrollEmployeePayrollCategoryWorkCode[] Xml_WorkCodes
{
    get;
    set;
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore()]
public PayrollEmployeePayrollDate[] PayrollEmployeePayrollDates
{
    get
    {
        if (Xml_PayrollDates == null || Xml_Hours == null || Xml_WorkCodes == null)
        {
            if (Xml_PayrollDates == null && Xml_Hours == null && Xml_WorkCodes == null)
            {
                return new PayrollEmployeePayrollDate[0];
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Mismatched PayrollDate/Hours/WorkCode");
            }
        }

        if (Xml_PayrollDates.Length != Xml_WorkCodes.Length || Xml_WorkCodes.Length != Xml_Hours.Length)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Mismatched PayrollDate/Hours/WorkCode");
        }

        var dates = new PayrollEmployeePayrollDate[Xml_PayrollDates.Length];

        for(int i = 0; i < dates.Length; i++)
        {
            dates[i] = new PayrollEmployeePayrollDate
            {
                Hours = Xml_Hours[i],
                WorkCode = Xml_WorkCodes[i],
                PayrollDate = Xml_PayrollDates[i]
            };
        }

        return dates;
    }
}
```

The elements will be deserialized in the order they appear in your XML by .NET, so if I'm interpreting your XML structure correctly, you can match everything back up again, because these elements always appear in the same order in the group, and each of the three elements in the group is always present if the others are present. This means that the `Hours` at index 0, `WorkCode` at index 0 and `TotalHours` at index 0 can all be packaged up into a single instance of your `PayrollEmployeePayrollDate`.

I haven't addressed writing back in the same XML format via this computed property, but from my understanding of your requirements you're just reading the data so this isn't needed.

Here's the full set of classes with the necessary adjustments to support this scheme (note that `PayrollEmployeePayrollDate` has been modified, and this class no longer plays a part in the XML serialization):

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class Payroll
{

    private System.DateTime startDateField;

    private System.DateTime endDateField;

    private System.DateTime postedDateField;

    private PayrollEmployee[] employeeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date")]
    public System.DateTime StartDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.startDateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.startDateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date")]
    public System.DateTime EndDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.endDateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.endDateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date")]
    public System.DateTime PostedDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.postedDateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.postedDateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Employee")]
    public PayrollEmployee[] Employee
    {
        get
        {
            return this.employeeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.employeeField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class PayrollEmployee
{

    private string employeePayStatusField;

    private string payrollStoreNumberField;

    private string reviewedDateField;

    private PayrollEmployeePayrollCategory[] payrollCategoryField;

    private int employeeIdField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string EmployeePayStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return this.employeePayStatusField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.employeePayStatusField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string PayrollStoreNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.payrollStoreNumberField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.payrollStoreNumberField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ReviewedDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.reviewedDateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.reviewedDateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PayrollCategory")]
    public PayrollEmployeePayrollCategory[] PayrollCategory
    {
        get
        {
            return this.payrollCategoryField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.payrollCategoryField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public int EmployeeId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.employeeIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.employeeIdField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class PayrollEmployeePayrollCategory
{
    private string categoryField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Category
    {
        get
        {
            return this.categoryField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.categoryField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PayrollDate", typeof(System.DateTime), DataType = "date")]
    public DateTime[] Xml_PayrollDates
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Hours", typeof(decimal))]
    public decimal[] Xml_Hours
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("WorkCode", typeof(PayrollEmployeePayrollCategoryWorkCode))]
    public PayrollEmployeePayrollCategoryWorkCode[] Xml_WorkCodes
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore()]
    public PayrollEmployeePayrollDate[] PayrollEmployeePayrollDates
    {
        get
        {
            if (Xml_PayrollDates == null || Xml_Hours == null || Xml_WorkCodes == null)
            {
                if (Xml_PayrollDates == null && Xml_Hours == null && Xml_WorkCodes == null)
                {
                    return new PayrollEmployeePayrollDate[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Mismatched PayrollDate/Hours/WorkCode");
                }
            }

            if (Xml_PayrollDates.Length != Xml_WorkCodes.Length || Xml_WorkCodes.Length != Xml_Hours.Length)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Mismatched PayrollDate/Hours/WorkCode");
            }

            var dates = new PayrollEmployeePayrollDate[Xml_PayrollDates.Length];

            for(int i = 0; i < dates.Length; i++)
            {
                dates[i] = new PayrollEmployeePayrollDate
                {
                    Hours = Xml_Hours[i],
                    WorkCode = Xml_WorkCodes[i],
                    PayrollDate = Xml_PayrollDates[i]
                };
            }

            return dates;
        }
    }

}

public partial class PayrollEmployeePayrollDate
{
    public DateTime PayrollDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public decimal Hours
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public PayrollEmployeePayrollCategoryWorkCode WorkCode
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class PayrollEmployeePayrollCategoryWorkCode
{

    private decimal totalHoursField;

    private int codeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TotalHours", typeof(decimal))]
    public decimal TotalHours
    {
        get
        {
            return this.totalHoursField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.totalHoursField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public int code
    {
        get
        {
            return this.codeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.codeField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Side note: you may find your classes easier to work with if you use `List<T>` instead of arrays, and arrange for the collection properties to have a default value of an empty collection (so you won't have to worry about checking both property is null and collection is empty if there are no child elements).

Comment: Oooohhhh...the reason I made that change is because when I would loop through the category, I would only get one date.  As the XML demonstrates, they could have up to 7 dates under each category.  So if I go back to the previous auto generated class, how do I get each date (if multiple) under a category and then for each date get the hours, work code and total hours?  That is where I am struggling.

Comment: BTW....the xml source is from a third party which I don't think we can get them to change the XML.  It looks like I am stuck with what I got.

Comment: So as I understand it, you have a group of 3 elements, and that group repeats. You want that group to be represented by a class. That's a reasonable XML structure, but I don't think .NET XML serialization supports it directly so there is probably not a clean solution. I'll have a look again later.

Comment: @JohnK: Answer now updated with a solution. Like I said before, there isn't a clean solution, but this does work with the XML in your question in my test code.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  I am implementing your suggestion now and may have some additional questions for you.